# Error in remote connect to SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-express

My program cannot connect to SQL Server 2008 Express remotely, the connection string is

```
Data Source=192.168.0.100\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=xxx;
Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=xxxx
```

I have checked all the configurations, the RemoteConnection is enabled, TCP/IP is enabled, the firewall closed, port is set 1433. And I have check the `telnet 192.168.0.100,1433`, it seems it connected successfully.

But when I check the `netstat -an` on the server, there is only `0,0,0,0:1433`, no `192.168.0.100:1433`, maybe there is something wrong about it.

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to connect server using SQL Management Studio from your system/pc?

Comment: no, I use my own program to connect the server.

Comment: what error do you get when you try to connect from your program?

Comment: Unable to connect to SQL Express "Error: 26-Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: Make sure you are using correct instance name and it is sqlexpress and not anyother value. Also make sure you enabled SQL Browser on server?

Comment: yes, I have enaled SQL Browser.

Comment: I think there should be a "TCP 192.168.0.100:1433 listening", but there is only 0,0,0,0:1433

Comment: 0.0.0.0:1433 Means that it is listening on all IP addresses that it can bind to on that port, you will generally only see the local IP:1433 combination when a connection is established, the fact that you can telnet to the port tells you it is open.

Answer (score 0):

Create a udl file, if it connects then the problem is th application, if it does not connect, then its your firewall, connections sting, connection library etc. Well the important thing here is probably the connection string. Do the following: create an empty text file and rename it "myconnection.udl". Now double click on the file and it will launch an applet. You can configuer the connection to your database and test it. Now open the udl file in notepad, you will see the correct connection string. Copy connections string to your app connection settings. UDL files are generally misunderstood. They are simply a text file that holds the connection settings. They then call the connection dll. If the udl file works then you have a correct connection string 100%